# SharedPreferences not reset on reinstall

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreference that counts the amount of launches of my App. I expect this to be 0, when I install my app. Nevertheless it is 14. The same strange behaviour I observe with my database, that already exists on a fresh install.

I didn't intent to recycle my app data (like in the Google Cloud). On my device in the account settings the app-data sync is on. If I turn it off, and make a reinstall I observe the same behaviour.

Anyone has every observed such a behaviour? Is there any way to prevent recycling old data and force a proper install?

Comment: Could this be because of the "Auto Backup" feature introduced in Android Marshmallow? [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

Comment: that's it! A lot of hair pulling for a single line of code ...

Comment: @Mauin make an answer and get credit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Android Marshmallow Google introduced the "Auto Backup" feature which is turned on by default if your targetSdkVersion is >=23.

This will back up your database and SharedPreferences by default and restore it when you re-install the application. To turn this feature off you have to add `android:allowBackup="false"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

More info here: [Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

Comment: For those who don't know which tag to add, it should be added to the application tag.

Answer (score 0):

Review your code in AndroidManifest on tag application if it has android:allowBackup="false". If you don't have (by default it's true), your app participates on android backup and restore infrastructure and can happen exactly what you say.

More information in this post: [What is "android:allowBackup"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648373/what-is-androidallowbackup)

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be handled from app side regarding shared Prefs.

Created a shared preference helper class and in the helper class have the below condition.

```
private static String SHARED_PREFS_VERSION = "SharedPrefsVersion"; // In this save the version of current shared Prefs.

void SharedPrefsHelper() {

    if( BuildConfig.Version > getSharedPrefsVersion() ) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.clear(); // Clear all the shared Prefs and update the current version.

        SetSharedPrefsVersion(BuildConfig.Version);

    }
}
```

For further reference look at :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381061/7364024